# Rounded corners become edgy when scrolling listview

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `ListView` in my Android app. The items have rounded corners defined like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<padding android:left="15dp" android:top="15dp" android:right="15dp"
    android:bottom="15dp" />
<solid android:color="@color/item_background" />
<corners android:radius="1dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="15dp" android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
    android:topRightRadius="15dp" />
</shape>
```

When the `ListView` is displayed everything looks fine. But as soon as I start scrolling, the rounded corners get edgy and as soon as the scrolling stops they become rounded again.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have a pretty good feeling this is just normal. The quality of what is in the listview is dropped so that while scrolling it can handle the movement and rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set XML attribute android:scrollingCache="false" in your ListView. If it won't help try also android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me because my ListView had `android:layout_height="0dp"`,
switch it to `android:layout_height="match_parent"`